# What is the good way of calculating the weight of every path in a TF2 neural network?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, interpretation

I'm trying to identify the most and least relevant input features of an ANN model (implemented with TF 2).
Since TF 2 returns the kernels and the bias calculated for each layer, the way to achieve so that I can imagine is
by recalculating the weights of every node in the model manually. As example, let's assume that my model have 4 input features,
one hidden layer with 2 nodes and a single node in the output layer.

```
    N1
    N2        N1         N1
    N3        N2
    N4
  layer0     layer1    layer2
```

Then my algorithm would look like this:

```
weight of path N11-N21-N31 = (layer[0].kernels[0] + layer[0].bias[0]) + (layer[1].kernels[0] + layer[1].bias[0]) + (layer[2].bias[0])

weight of path N11-N22-N31: (layer[0].kernels[0] + layer[0].bias[0]) + (layer[1].kernels[1] + layer[1].bias[1]) + (layer[2].bias[0])

...
```

Though I think this mechanism can work, I still have some questions:

1. What's the operator to concatenate the weights of two layers (addition, multiplication, other)? I mean:

```
(layer[0].kernels[0] + layer[0].bias[0]) + (layer[1].kernels[0] + layer[1].bias[0])
```

or

```
(layer[0].kernels[0] + layer[0].bias[0]) * (layer[1].kernels[0] + layer[1].bias[0])
```

2. Does Keras or TF provide an automatic tool or API to get this info?

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras.Model``` ?

Comment: @DachuanZhao, my model is a tf.keras.Model. I just want to know how the input features are weighted during training. I can access the kernels and bias of every layer through the API but I'm not sure if I should add or multiply between layers. In any case, if there were a built-in too for doing so it'd be great.